# Trying to map "similar looking" tuples returned from multiple functions to one variable

Tags: c#

Say there is a library with code of this form:

```
 public class SomeLib
{
    public (bool WasOk, string Message) DoCheck(string fileName)
    {
        // do something here to check the file. 
        return (true, "all good");
    }

    public (bool WasOk, string Message) DoCheck(byte[] fileBytes)
    {
        // do something here to check the file as bytes 
        return (true, "all good");
    }
}
```

The code which uses this library looks of this form:

```
    int option = 1;

    SomeLib lib = new SomeLib();

    if (option == 0)
    {
        var res1 = lib.DoCheck("hello");
        MessageBox.Show(res1.WasOk + res1.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        var res2 = lib.DoCheck(new byte[] { });
        MessageBox.Show(res2.WasOk + res2.Message);
    }
```

What I was hoping to do, was to store the returned value from the two calls to DoCheck, to a common variable. e.g.:

```
    int option = 1;

    SomeLib lib = new SomeLib();

    var res; // doesn't compile, obviously

    if (option == 0)
    {
        res = lib.DoCheck("hello");                
    }
    else
    {
        res = lib.DoCheck(new byte[] { });
    }

    MessageBox.Show(res.WasOk + res.Message);  // act on the result in the same way for both branches.
```

I hope this makes sense. Is what I am trying to do possible? Let's say that the code in the library cannot be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var res` doesn't compile because it doesn't have any type information. If you're making a statement that declares a variable the compiler has to be able to work out the type somehow, either from the left or the right side:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //both sides, available from the dawn of time
var sb = new StringBuilder();           //for a long time
StringBuilder sb = new();               //more recently
```

If there isn't a right side then the left side has to have the type info:

```
StringBuilder sb;
```

Thus for your case you need to put the type info on the left. You can even rename the members (but you don't have to)

```
(bool AllGood, string Note) res;

(bool WasOk, string Message) res;

(bool, string) res;  //access the bool in res.Item1, string in res.Item2
```

---

You could do it in a one with a ternary:

```
var res = (option == 0) ? lib.DoCheck(hello) : lib.DoCheck(new byte[] { });
```

Both your methods return tuples with the same named members so your `res` will have `res.WasOk` and `res.Message` so it's compiled as if it's this:

```
(bool WasOk, string Message) res = ...
```

If your tuples coming out your methods had different names it would still compile as if it was this:

```
(bool, string) res = ...
```

And you  could still access the data via Item1 and Item2

---

If you're doing this ternary approach then you could deconstruct the tuple too, which also allows you to rename:

```
var(allGood, note) = ... ? ... : ... ;

MessageBox.Show(note);
```

Instead of one tuple variable where you say `res.Whatever`, this has created two variables like as if you'd done this:

```
var res = ... ? ... : ... ;
var allGood = res.WasOk;
var note = res.Message;
```

Plenty of options for dealing with tuples..

Answer (score 1):

**Implicitly typed locals must be initialized**

> An implicitly typed local variable must be initialized with a value at the same time that it is declared. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0818?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0818))

### To correct this error

Assign a value to the variable or else give it an explicit type.

```
(bool AllGood, string Note) res;
```